# builder pattern and limiting implicit object creation

Tags: java, design-patterns

If I use builder pattern that create some PRODUCT, i would, probably should want to limit the ability to create this PRODUCT by explicit way?

Because it is probably not good of users of my code would create PRODUCT like new PRODUCT().

I mean the users of my code my do not know about some builder.

So, should I make constructor of PRODUCT with as private? And then in the Builder I would use reflection to create the initial instance of the PRODUCT?

Does this approach make sense? Is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

Or you set the constructor as protected, and create a builder in the same package, so it has access to it, or create static methods that might even use your builder implicitly.

Comment: Additionally I'd add a hint to the `Product` class' JavaDoc that instances may be obtained from the `ProductBuilder` (or whatever it's called).

Comment: yes. or stay it as is, as package level. but then i will have a lot of packages with two classes - product & its builder. i would be not nice structure i guess.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be describing is called the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (rather than the builder pattern).

The simplest way to implement this is to make your constructor private and provide static factory methods on the Product class. This is the bare minimum implementation:

```
public class Product {
    private Product() {}

    public static Product create() {
        return new Product();
    }
}
```

There are plenty of classes in the JDK that follow this pattern, for example [Integer.parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) is static factory method the creates as `Integer` (although the constructor is not private)

Alternatively, you could create a separate Factory class in the same package as Product and give the Product constructor the default visibility.

You should avoid using reflection in general, unless you really need it. In this case you don't need it - keep things as simple as possible (but no simpler).

Comment: sometimes not very nice when PRODUCT can handle its own creation (by Factory method), with logical point of view. So, to use a reflection it is very bad you think?

Comment: Yeah, that's the factory pattern. But the question was about the builder pattern, which is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ProductBuilder` is able to create an instance of `Product` through reflection, then any other class can do the same.

I think, it's easier to add builder and product to the same namespace (package) and make the constructor package private. It has the same effect (invisible for classes outside the package) and keeps the code clean.

Comment: But then I may have a lot of packages with two classes - product & its builder. I would be not nice structure I guess. I think, for example, if i make constructor private, it should say that YOU should not create this object such way. But yes then could use the reflection, but they would think first, 'maybe there is a builder somewhere which could create this object of that class'

Comment: @ses - why? You can put all different products and all of their builders in one package. As long as the *users* don't put their classes in the same package, the solution fits your needs: the *users* can't initiate product classes. - And, a package private constructor, maybe accompagnied with an explaining javadoc ("only to be called by builder") will have the same effect like making it private.